# How can I achieve this using gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

I am enumerating the subdirectories in a directory. For each sub directory I would like to apply a number of gulp activities like less compilation, and then create an output file specific to that subdirectory.

I would like the gulp process to continue, as further transformation steps need to be performed later.

Can someone help me understand how I can create these files half way through the "gulp pipeline"?

Comment: None of those steps seems particularly challenging on its own; which one is giving you the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems quite interesting to achieve and gulp has no limitations at all.

I will give you detailed example how I have managed to accomplish such a task a while ago.

Let assume that you have directoryA. Subdirectories childA, childB and childC are contained into directoryA. So basically your tree structure looks like:

```
directoryA
--childA
--childB
--childC
```

I am always looking for a flexible solutions so I would suggest to include a JSON file in each subdirectory naming the tasks you would like to running. Using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) you can access these files. You can also use run-sequence to execute gulp tasks synchronously.

For demo purposes place a file named manifest.json inside childA subdirectory.

Manifest.json contains the following declarations:

```
{
    "filesToProccess" : ["./childA/*.js", "./childB/*.js"],
    "tasksToRun" :["taskA", "taskB"]
}
```

Finally gulpfile would like this:

```
'use strict';

//dependencies declared into package.json
//install them using npm

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    path = require('path');


//these two array will keep the actions you have included into manifest file.
var filesHolder = [], tasksHolder = [];

gulp.task('taskA', function () { 
    return gulp.src(filesHolder)
    .pipe(whatever)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('whatever')); //chailed actions 
});


gulp.task('taskB', function () { 
    return gulp.src(filesHolder)
    .pipe(whatever)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('whatever')); 
});

//a simple utility function to read all subdirectories of directoryA

function getDirectories(srcpath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
  });
}



//finally insert the default gulp task
gulp.task('default', function(){

    var manifest;

    //map directory's A subdirectories
    var availableDirs = getDirectories("./directoryA");

    //finally loop the available subdirectories, load each manifest file and 
    availableDirs.forEach(function(subdir) {
        manifest = require("./directoryA/"+subdir+"manifest.json");
        filesHolder = manifest.filesToProccess;
        tasksHolder = manifest.tasksToRun;
        runSequence( tasksHolder , function () {
            console.log( " Task ended :" + tasksHolder + " for subdirectory : " + subdir); 
        });

    });

});
```